# Python def function prints the prompt message when it is defined

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.41.

If I understand the following thread,
[Why is this def function not being executed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5400473/3988805)
correctly, defining a function in Python will store the function away and will not execute it unless called. Am I right?

I want to search for a list of divisors for a number, store that in a tuple and print that out.

First I wrote,

```
if x < 0:
    print ('not positive')
else:
    div = ()
    for i in range(1, x):
        if x%i == 0:
            div = div + (i,)
    print (div)
```

this works.

now I want this as a function for a larger code. Here is the code I have tried.

```
def find_dt(x = int(input('enter a positive number '))):
    if x < 0:
        print ('not positive')
    else:
        div = ()
        for i in range(1, x):
            if x%i == 0:
                div = div + (i,)
        print (div)
```

When I execute this, in the program window it prints the prompt message for the function without calling it. Also if I type a number in, it returns nothing. I was expecting nothing apparent to happen in the program window.

Would you elaborate what is happening and teach me how to write it correctly for the purpose that I want? I hope my question is clear enough.

thanks,

Comment: While we check out the issue, it'd be nice and help us out if you'd format your code a little better

Comment: Sorry for the terrible readability, I'll look in to it. thanks.

Comment: I thought you need four spaces and a > to be blocked out in the post. I edited the question, I hope it is better now.

Comment: Yes it is much better. Thanks

Comment: default arguments are evaluated ad definition time in Python. see e.g. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: qarma thanks for the link. It is very informative. good karma for you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing the prompt because you're putting the call to `input()` in the function definition's *arguments* - specifically, as a default value, which is evaluated at definition time.

It sounds like what you actually want is a function that doesn't take any arguments, and calls `input()` only when run:

```
def find_dt():
    x = int(input('enter a positive number: '))

    if x < 0:
        print ('not positive')
    ...
```

Comment: I see! I am surprised how fast I got a response. Thank you.

Comment: Though oftentimes it is a better design to do the `input` in the caller, and write functions with no external interactions.

Comment: @tripleee All depends on the desired result.

Comment: Rarely is the desired result a function which cannot be reused, and so might as well be inlined to the code which calls it.

Comment: @tripleee You're looking at this from the perspective of a career programmer. The feeling I'm getting from the OP is of someone just starting to learn. There might not even be "code which calls it". Sometimes providing too much information is a worse learning experience then a concise answer to a single issue.